# R: ggmap: containing missing values (geom_point) when plottinng but no NAs values found in data.frame

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm plotting some points over a map with ggmap package.

The problem is that i get the message: **"Removed 12 rows containing missing values (geom_point)"**.

But i don't have any NAs. I've looked the data, and used:

```
sum(is.na(limanov2)) #Gives 0
```

to prove it.

This is my code:

```
library(maps)
library(ggmap)

lima <- get_map(location = "lima", zoom = 11)

    ggmap(lima) + geom_point(data = limanov2, aes(x = LONGITUD , y = LATITUD, color = TOTALES,
                                                      size = TOTALES)) +
            scale_color_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red")
```

My data:

```
structure(list(DISTRITO = c("SAN JUAN DE LURIGANCHO", "CALLAO", 
"LOS OLIVOS", "ATE VITARTE", "LIMA CERCADO", "SAN MARTÍN", "SANTIAGO DE SURCO", 
"CHORILLOS", "COMAS", "INDEPENDENCIA", "EL AGUSTINO", "LA VICTORIA", 
"SAN JUAN DE MIRAFLORES", "VILLA EL SALVADOR", "S. MIGUEL", "CARABAYLLO", 
"MIRAFLORES", "PTE. PIEDRA", "SAN BORJA", "VENTANILLA", "SURQUILLO", 
"BREÑA", "ANCÓN", "EL RIMAC", "BARRANCO", "LA MOLINA", "SAN LUIS", 
"STA. ANITA", "LURIGANCHO", "P. LIBRE", "MAGDALENA", "LA PERLA", 
"CHACLACAYO", "SAN ISIDRO", "J. MARÍA", "BELLAVISTA", "LINCE", 
"C. DE LA LEGUA", "CIENEGUILLA", "STA.ROSA", "LURÍN", "PTA.NEGRA", 
"PUCUSANA", "LA PUNTA", "PTA. HERMOSA", "PACHACAMAC", "SAN BARTOLO", 
"SANTA MARÍA"), TOTALES = c(861L, 696L, 696L, 642L, 516L, 479L, 
442L, 378L, 371L, 368L, 361L, 333L, 325L, 291L, 282L, 251L, 239L, 
223L, 196L, 193L, 188L, 185L, 174L, 161L, 138L, 134L, 128L, 119L, 
115L, 105L, 67L, 65L, 63L, 58L, 56L, 45L, 38L, 23L, 23L, 11L, 
8L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L), HOMICIDIOS = c(1L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 7L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), LESIONES = c(100L, 
72L, 61L, 43L, 44L, 8L, 10L, 15L, 44L, 40L, 50L, 15L, 52L, 28L, 
7L, 33L, 15L, 27L, 3L, 21L, 7L, 36L, 33L, 19L, 14L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 
16L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), VIO..DE.LA.LIBERTAD.PERSONAL = c(0L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), VIO..DE.LA.LIBERTAD.SEXUAL = c(56L, 
14L, 12L, 15L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 14L, 4L, 
15L, 4L, 12L, 2L, 17L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 11L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), HURTO.SIMPLE.Y.AGRAVADO = c(217L, 203L, 296L, 230L, 
260L, 167L, 226L, 217L, 130L, 117L, 154L, 133L, 121L, 46L, 163L, 
72L, 161L, 84L, 119L, 69L, 120L, 64L, 19L, 21L, 57L, 44L, 39L, 
2L, 48L, 60L, 30L, 19L, 48L, 41L, 25L, 19L, 27L, 7L, 11L, 9L, 
0L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L), ROBO.SIMPLE.Y.AGRAVADO = c(460L, 
289L, 308L, 344L, 186L, 277L, 198L, 130L, 165L, 184L, 137L, 149L, 
134L, 188L, 104L, 126L, 58L, 96L, 72L, 64L, 51L, 77L, 115L, 76L, 
64L, 88L, 73L, 108L, 40L, 36L, 30L, 32L, 14L, 12L, 22L, 12L, 
8L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), MICRO.COM.DE.DROGAS = c(26L, 
100L, 13L, 3L, 10L, 15L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 8L, 3L, 23L, 9L, 15L, 3L, 
3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), TENENCIA.ILEGAL.DE.ARMAS = c(1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), LONGITUD = c(-77, -77.12, 
-77.08, -76.89, -77.04, -77.09, -76.99, -77.01, -77.05, -77.05, 
-77, -77.02, -76.97, -76.94, -77.09, -76.99, -77.03, -77.08, 
-77, -77.13, -77.01, -77.05, -77.11, -76.7, -77.02, -76.92, -77, 
-76.96, -76.86, -77.06, -77.07, -77.12, -76.76, -77.03, -77.05, 
-77.11, -77.04, -77.09, -76.78, -77.16, -76.81, -76.73, -76.77, 
-77.16, -76.76, -76.83, -76.73, -76.77), LATITUD = c(-11.99, 
-12.04, -11.97, -12.04, -12.06, -12, -12.16, -12.2, -11.93, -11.99, 
-12.04, -12.08, -12.16, -12.23, -12.08, -11.79, -12.12, -11.88, 
-12.1, -11.89, -12.11, -12.06, -11.69, -11.94, -12.15, -12.09, 
-12.08, -12.04, -11.98, -12.08, -12.09, -12.07, -11.99, -12.1, 
-12.08, -12.06, -12.09, -12.04, -12.07, -11.81, -12.24, -12.32, 
-12.47, -12.07, -12.28, -12.18, -12.38, -12.42)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -48L), .Names = c("DISTRITO", 
"TOTALES", "HOMICIDIOS", "LESIONES", "VIO..DE.LA.LIBERTAD.PERSONAL", 
"VIO..DE.LA.LIBERTAD.SEXUAL", "HURTO.SIMPLE.Y.AGRAVADO", "ROBO.SIMPLE.Y.AGRAVADO", 
"MICRO.COM.DE.DROGAS", "TENENCIA.ILEGAL.DE.ARMAS", "LONGITUD", 
"LATITUD"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have values outside of the base map zoom range... try changing your zoom parameter.

```
library(maps)
library(ggmap)

lima <- get_map(location = "lima", zoom = 10)

ggmap(lima) + 
  geom_point(data = limanov2, 
             aes(x = LONGITUD , y = LATITUD, 
                 color = TOTALES, size = TOTALES)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red")
```

Comment: This is the solution, thanks. The problem is that the labels for districs on the map get changed: some stay, some go away when using zoom = 10. Do you know how to download the map without labels? Then i could use a geom_text to put the "names of DISTRITOS" as labels for the points.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that with the ggmap package. I've had luck with using the OpenStreetMap package using the type parameter in openmap() to select a type of map tile to use. Some have district names, some have none, but you have a lot to choose from. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OpenStreetMap/index.html

Comment: i've spend the day looking for a way to do this map: [link]https://raw.githubusercontent.com/corynissen/foodbornechi_research/master/output/chi_restaurant_count_by_ward.png[/link]. I need to do that for "Lima" capital of Perú, and then use colors for Districs. May you give some light on this?

Comment: Whoa, that's my map! Any how, you need the district boundary GIS shapefile. A login is needed for this one... http://landscapeportal.org/people/profile/martin_r/?content=all&sortby=title  . It's the only one I can find.